# Grammar errors in Xtext

Tags: parsing, xtext

I have a grammar rule

```
factoid:
Element Place
;
```

That depends on another rule:

```
Place:
name = ('sea' | 'air')
;
```

The factoid rule seems to contain identify errors associated with Place:

> Multiple markers at this line
>   - Cannot change type twice within a rule
>   - An unassigned rule call is not allowed, when the 'current'
>     was already created.

I have no idea what this means. Can someone explain what this is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

I think the *Element* rule generates an object. Since there is no assignment this becomes the *current* one. The second unassigned rule call to *Place* would also return an object. But the current pointer contains already the *Element* type class and can not contain the class *Place* as well. So what you can try is assigning the *Place* to a member of *factoid*, here called *location* :

```
factoid:
 item=Element location=Place
;
```

I am not sure if the assignment of *Element* to *item* is required. If Element is not assigned to member then I expect that *location* would become member of *Element* or something similar.